# Unity3D: How to show GUI.box if condition is true?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity3D with C#. I am using GUI.box to show a healthbar for the mobs, but I only want to show the GUI.box if there is a target.

This is my code at the moment.

```
public GameObject target;
public bool existsTarget;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

PlayerAttack pa = (PlayerAttack)GetComponent("PlayerAttack");
target = pa.target;

existsTarget = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

if(target != null)
existsTarget = true;
else
existsTarget = false;


}

void OnGUI()
{
if(existsTarget)
        GUI.Box(new Rect(500, 10, healthBarLength, 20), curHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
    else   {
       GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width, 10, healthBarLength, 20), curHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
   }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't show any healthbars at all. Any ideas as to why?

Posting the scripts here after popular demand.

```
public class Targetting : MonoBehaviour {
public List<Transform> targets;
public List<Transform> items;
public GameObject TheSelectedTarget {get; set;}
private Transform selectedTarget;
private Transform selectedItem;
private Transform myTransform;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    targets = new List<Transform>();
    items = new List<Transform>();

    selectedTarget = null;
    selectedItem = null;
    myTransform = transform;
    TheSelectedTarget = null;

    addAllEnemies();
    addAllItems();
}

//adds all targets to a list
private void addAllEnemies() {

    GameObject[] go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

    foreach(GameObject enemy in go){
        addTarget(enemy.transform);
    }

}

//adds a target
private void addTarget(Transform enemy) {

    targets.Add(enemy);
}

//sorts target by distance
private void sortTargets() {

    targets.Sort(delegate(Transform t1, Transform t2) {
        return Vector3.Distance(t1.position, myTransform.position).CompareTo(Vector3.Distance(t2.position, myTransform.position));
    });
}

//targets an enemy
private void targetEnemy() {

    addAllEnemies();

    if(selectedTarget == null) {
        sortTargets();
        selectedTarget = targets[0];
    } else {
        int index = targets.IndexOf(selectedTarget);

        if(index < targets.Count -1) {
            index++;

        } else {
            index = 0;

        } 
        deselectTarget();
        selectedTarget = targets[index];
}
    selectTarget();
    targets.Clear();
    }
//selects a specific target, and colors it red
public void selectTarget() {

    selectedTarget.renderer.material.color = Color.red;

    PlayerAttack pa = (PlayerAttack)GetComponent("PlayerAttack");
    pa.target = selectedTarget.gameObject;

    TheSelectedTarget = pa.target;
}

//deselects the current selected target, and colors i grey
private void deselectTarget() {
    selectedTarget.renderer.material.color = Color.gray;
    selectedTarget = null;
}

//adds all items to a list
void addAllItems() {

GameObject[] go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Book");

foreach(GameObject book in go){
    addItem(book.transform);
}
```

}

'

.... And then the script continues but without any relevance to this...

```
'          public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
          {
            public string enemyName;
              public int maxHealth = 100;
              public int curHealth = 100;
              public float healthBarLength;
              public GameObject target;
          public bool existsTarget;
          public AudioSource dying;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
{
    //enemyName = this.enemyName;
    healthBarLength = Screen.width / 3;

    existsTarget = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    adjustCurHealth(0);

    Targetting ta = (Targetting)GetComponent("Targetting");
    target = ta.TheSelectedTarget;
    Debug.Log (target);

    if(target != null)
        existsTarget = true;
    else {
        existsTarget = false;   
    }

}

void OnGUI()
{
    if(existsTarget)
        GUI.Box(new Rect(500, 10, healthBarLength, 20), curHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
    else   {
       GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width, 10, healthBarLength, 20), curHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
   }
}

public void adjustCurHealth(int adj)
{
    curHealth += adj;

    if (curHealth < 0)
        curHealth = 0;

    if (curHealth > 100)
        curHealth = 100;

    if (maxHealth < 0)
        maxHealth = 1;

    if(curHealth == 0)
    {
        //dying.Play ();
        GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    healthBarLength = (Screen.width / 3) * (curHealth / (float)maxHealth);
}
```

}

Comment: Double check your position parameters for your box.  I'm guessing you're telling it to be off the screen, or 0 length.

Comment: I'm also thinking that the position parameter is the problem here, try with a bigger one (200x50) at the origin to see what happens. By the way, isn't it easier to check the condition `target != null` in `OnGUI()`? Keep in mind that this method may be called more than once per frame.

Comment: Thanks for comments!

I don't think it is the position parameters, because the GUI.box shows perfectly fine if I simply take away the if conditions. At first I made sure the GUI.box showed properly, but then I saw the healthbars for all mobs all the time, which is not very good of course -.- 

My first attempt was to have the condition in OnGUI(), but that didn't work, so I assumed it isn't updated on each frame, so I moved it to Update(). Tried again now, but didn't work.

Comment: I think we need to see the `PlayerAttack` script to know exactly what is going on...

Comment: @user1776119 If you take the condition away you're drawing 2 independent boxes.  Your second box starts drawing at the edge of the screen and won't show up unless healthBarLength is negative, but negative Rect lengths result in incorrect boxes.  I ran your code w/o conditions and only the first box draws but that makes sense, it's drawn in at x=500.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Are you ever setting the target anywhere other than the Start() method? The code you show will only ever show a GUI.box if the PlayerAttack.Target is not null at the start. Try moving this code to the Update() method.

```
PlayerAttack pa = (PlayerAttack)GetComponent("PlayerAttack");
target = pa.target;
```

Edit:

Check to see if the target is null, that could be the issue.

```
target = pa.target;
Debug.Log(target);
```

This will either print to the log as whatever GameObject it is, or null. If it's null, then there is no target.

Comment: is the PlayerAttack script attached to the same component where you are trying to get it from?

Comment: No it wasn't. Just attached it, but that didn't work either :(

Comment: If you have attached it through AddComponent you MUST be able to retrieve it back with GetComponent method.

Comment: I just dragged it onto the gameobjects. It's a rather small game so :P Is there something else I need to do then?

Comment: @user1776119: so the object has 2 script?check the inspector, it must show that your object has a PlayerAttack script and the other (I don't know the name) where you are calling GetComponent

Comment: Yeah, it has both PlayerAttack script as well as the EnemyHealth script where I am making the healthbar

Comment: I just added the Debug.Log(target) and it returns null. I think the problem then is that pa.target = target returns the target from PlayerAttack script attached to the enemy, instead of the target from PlayerAttack script attached to the player. But I'm not sure how to fix that :/

Comment: Take the PlayerAttack script off the Enemy, just leave it on the Player. If target still shows up as null, then it has to be that the Player's PlayerAttack.Target is null. At that point, click and drag the Enemy GameObject and drop it into the Player's PlayerAttack.Target property. When you run it this time, it should not be null.

Comment: I doesn't get far enough to the Debug.Log actually, it gets a nullreferencexception: object reference is not set to an instance of an object on the line target = pa.target in EnemyHealth script. But target in PlayerAttack script on PlayerCharacter works, so the problem is probably there in getting correct target. Again, not sure how to fix that -.-

Comment: Then there are issues in other scripts. Can you post your PlayerAttack and EnemyHealth scripts?

Comment: When you call selectTarget() in your Targetting script, is it highlighting the enemy?